# Split the Sub-String from a String in Excel

Tags: excel, macros, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

For Example Here is the String in Cell A1:

Product Image File: 2eeb_1_b__57081.JPG

Product Image URL: http://www.example.com/product_images/p/759/2eeb_1_b__57081.JPG

Product Image File: r__06677.jpg

Product Image URL: http://www.example.com/product_images/e/130/r__06677.jpg

It Contains two Image URLs I want to Populate These two URLs in Cell B1 and C1.

Comment: Can't you just use Text to column (Data Ribbon) and set the separator to a comma?

Comment: It's a pity that there is a comma after the second file name, but not after the first one - is that just poor copy/pasting into this question or is that really how your data is set out?

Comment: there are total 2 URLs. I want to get these two URLs form mentioned String and Place them to two separate Columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this formula in `B1`:

```
=IFERROR(MID($A1,
SEARCH("http:",$A1),
SEARCH(".jpg",$A1,SEARCH("http:",$A1))
-SEARCH("http:",$A1)+LEN(".jpg")),"")
```

Enter this formula in `C1`:

```
=IFERROR(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),
SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,"")),
SEARCH(".jpg",SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),
SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,"")))
-SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""))+LEN(".jpg")),"")
```

Enter this formula in `D1`:

```
=IFERROR(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),
SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,"")),
SEARCH(".jpg",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),
SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,"")))
-SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""))+LEN(".jpg")),"")
```

Enter this formula in `E1`:

```
=IFERROR(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),$D1,""),
SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),$D1,"")),
SEARCH(".jpg",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),$D1,""),
SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),$D1,"")))
-SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),$D1,""))+LEN(".jpg")),"")
```

and this formula in `F1`:

```
=IFERROR(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),$D1,""),$E1,""),
SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),$D1,""),$E1,"")),
SEARCH(".jpg",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),$D1,""),$E1,""),
SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),$D1,""),$E1,"")))
-SEARCH("http:",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,$B1,""),$C1,""),$D1,""),$E1,""))+LEN(".jpg")),"")
```

Comment: Perfect! That is what I am exactly looking for.
Thank you Stay Blessed!

Comment: What if there are are more than 2 URL in String and we want to populate in D1, E1 etc ?

Comment: Please edit your answer up to 5 URL. Its Greatly Helpful and solved my problem of the day. Please remember URL should not be repeat.

Comment: So you could have up to five urls, and that can include repetitions. It's that correct?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your original question. Meanwhile i'll look into the additional urls thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set b1=left(a1,150); set c1=right(a1, 150)
(Play with 150 for the best length)

Paste special/values in b1/c1

B1: find *url:    and replace with nothing

B1: find jpg*     and replace with jpg

C1: find *url:    and replace with nothing

You can do this for columns B and C instead of just cells.